# Is there an efficient way to fill date gaps in python?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I fetch my documents from MongoDB as below:

```
    {
      "amount": 1200,
      "date_closed": "2012-07-02 17:00:00"
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-03 16:00:00"
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-04 20:00:00"
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-04 22:00:00"
    }
```

I get a timestamp like `1343287040` from user(parameter called `user_time`) which refers to date `datetime.datetime(2012, 7, 26, 11, 47, 20)`.

---

**This is my solution to fill gaps:**
Now I create a date format `YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00` by the below code:

```
hourly_date = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_time).year) + '-' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_time).month) + '-' + str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(user_time).day) + ' 00:00:00'
```

`user_time` is the start date. Now I generate hourly records from `user_time` until today. The below code generate date range in hour with the format I want:

```
date_range = pandas.date_range(start=hourly_date, end=datetime.datetime.today(), freq='H')
                    date_range = date_range.values.astype('<M8[h]').astype(str)
                    hourly_date = []
                    for i_hourly in date_range:
                        tmp_date = pandas.to_datetime(str(i_hourly)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
                        hourly_date.append(tmp_date)
```

After creating a template date range in hour from `user_time` until today, I compare it with my `date_closed` field which is returned from MongoDB:

```
records_len = len(records)
                    for i_hourly in hourly_date:
                        i = 0
                        for record in records:
                            i += 1
                            if i_hourly in record['date_closed']:
                                break  # break from innermost loop

                            elif records_len == i and i_hourly not in record['date_closed']:
                                records.append({"amount": 0, "date_closed": i_hourly})
```

`records` contains many field lets say from 2012 until today, the problem I want to solve is to see is the date and hour is missing from returned document. If it is missing then we need to add it to records to fill the gap, otherwise I should break from the innermost loop.

This code takes about 57 seconds! This is a huge amount of time. Is there a better an more efficient way to generate date gaps in hour?

---

**EDIT:**

```
     amount    date_closed
0      21800 2015-07-21 10:00:00
1       5450 2015-07-05 04:00:00
2     571160 2015-06-22 12:00:00
3      65400 2015-06-15 12:00:00
4      10900 2015-06-15 09:00:00
5     109000 2015-06-14 07:00:00
6     109000 2015-06-14 04:00:00
7    1193550 2015-06-11 06:00:00
8      10900 2015-06-11 05:00:00
9      21800 2015-06-09 10:00:00
10     10900 2015-05-31 05:00:00
11         0 2015-05-30 09:00:00
12    114450 2015-05-19 13:00:00
13    261600 2015-05-19 08:00:00
14    108000 2015-05-11 08:00:00
15      2180 2015-05-11 07:00:00
16    344870 2015-05-05 13:00:00
17     70850 2015-05-05 12:00:00
18      5450 2015-05-05 05:00:00
19    109000 2015-05-03 12:00:00
20    327000 2015-05-03 11:00:00
21    310650 2015-04-30 05:00:00
22     38150 2015-04-28 13:00:00
23     26160 2015-04-27 07:00:00
24    109000 2015-04-22 12:00:00
25     97200 2015-03-09 08:00:00
26     21800 2015-07-11 05:00:00
27     26160 2015-05-20 05:00:00
28     37800 2015-03-03 07:00:00
29    130800 2015-06-29 06:00:00
..       ...                 ...
161     2180 2015-05-25 09:00:00
162    26160 2015-05-09 11:00:00
163   108000 2015-03-03 11:00:00
164  3337200 2014-09-13 05:00:00
165  5249880 2014-09-10 05:00:00
166   712800 2014-08-10 09:00:00
167   151200 2015-02-23 06:00:00
168    48600 2014-08-10 11:00:00
169     6540 2015-04-19 10:00:00
170   172800 2014-09-01 09:00:00
171  1370520 2014-10-15 09:00:00
172   421200 2014-07-26 09:00:00
173    86400 2015-03-01 12:00:00
174   118800 2015-02-21 12:00:00
175    97200 2014-09-17 07:00:00
176    54500 2015-04-23 07:00:00
177  1185840 2014-09-09 06:00:00
178   119016 2015-02-18 09:00:00
179    32400 2014-11-05 08:00:00
180   345600 2014-08-09 10:00:00
181   151200 2015-02-18 12:00:00
182   168480 2014-10-09 06:00:00
183  5668920 2014-10-04 21:00:00
184   669600 2014-08-06 12:00:00
185   194400 2014-08-02 07:00:00
186   313920 2015-06-23 08:00:00
187     6540 2015-05-04 09:00:00
188   669600 2014-07-23 10:00:00
189    64800 2015-01-22 06:00:00
190   669600 2014-08-25 04:00:00
[191 rows x 2 columns]
```

It shows that I just have 191 records these are returned from Mongo! I wanted to see a list of hourly generated list which is around 121000 records and 191 records of it will be filled by the above code.

The problem is that I suppose these two list are not merged together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first make `date_closed` column as the index and then `.reindex` according to `hourly_date_rng` to populate the missing records.

Here is an example.

```
import json
import pandas as pd

json_data = [
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-04 16:00:00"
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-04 20:00:00"
    },
    {
      "amount": 0,
      "date_closed": "2012-08-04 22:00:00"
    }
]

df = pd.read_json(json.dumps(json_data), orient='records')
df

   amount          date_closed
0       0  2012-08-03 16:00:00
1       0  2012-08-04 20:00:00
2       0  2012-08-04 22:00:00
```

The `hourly_date_rng` looks like this

```
hourly_date_rng = pd.date_range(start='2012-08-04 12:00:00', end='2012-08-4 23:00:00', freq='H')
hourly_date_rng.name = 'date_closed'

hourly_date_rng

DatetimeIndex(['2012-08-04 12:00:00', '2012-08-04 13:00:00',
               '2012-08-04 14:00:00', '2012-08-04 15:00:00',
               '2012-08-04 16:00:00', '2012-08-04 17:00:00',
               '2012-08-04 18:00:00', '2012-08-04 19:00:00',
               '2012-08-04 20:00:00', '2012-08-04 21:00:00',
               '2012-08-04 22:00:00', '2012-08-04 23:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date_closed', freq='H', tz=None)
```

To align the index and fill the gaps

```
# make the column datetime object instead of string
df['date_closed'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_closed'])
# align the index using .reindex
df.set_index('date_closed').reindex(hourly_date_rng).fillna(0).reset_index()

           date_closed  amount
0  2012-08-04 12:00:00       0
1  2012-08-04 13:00:00       0
2  2012-08-04 14:00:00       0
3  2012-08-04 15:00:00       0
4  2012-08-04 16:00:00       0
5  2012-08-04 17:00:00       0
6  2012-08-04 18:00:00       0
7  2012-08-04 19:00:00       0
8  2012-08-04 20:00:00       0
9  2012-08-04 21:00:00       0
10 2012-08-04 22:00:00       0
11 2012-08-04 23:00:00       0
```

### Edit:

To convert back the result to JSON.

```
result = df.set_index('date_closed').reindex(hourly_date_rng).fillna(0).reset_index()

# maybe convert date_closed column to string first
result['date_closed'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(result['date_closed']).to_native_types()
# to json function
json_result = result.to_json(orient='records')

# print out the data with pretty print
from pprint import pprint
pprint(json.loads(json_result))


[{'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 12:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 13:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 14:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 15:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 16:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 17:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 18:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 19:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 20:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 21:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 22:00:00'},
 {'amount': 0.0, 'date_closed': '2012-08-04 23:00:00'}]
```

Comment: I think data has not been merged in a correct way! Output shows 191 records returned.

Comment: @phpGeek the last line of the code return a copy of the result, and it does not modify your original df. Can you try `result = df.set_index('date_closed').reindex(hourly_date_rng).fillna(0).reset_index()` and then `print(result)` to see how many records are there?

Comment: Ahhhh my mistake! Printing `result` now displays `26653` records. Sorry how can I convert this data frame into a json I need: `{"amount": "12", "date_closed": "2012-01-02 12:12:11"}`

Comment: @phpGeek You can use `df.to_json(orient='records')`. See the edited part.

Comment: @phpGeek You are most welcome. Glad that it helped. :-)